# Which Facebook like button should I have?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have 3 options for having the like button:

1. My Facebook App
2. My domain URL running the app
3. Fan page

I am more inclined towards using #2 as it will post a thumbnail on the user's wall and help promotion. What do I miss in #1? #3 looks very useless to me at the moment as fanpage is just a placeholder as of now.

Should I use one or two? And how much #1 is important for an app which is going to be viral?

Comment: I guess number 1 is useless and number 3 depends if your app is made to word inside a tab in a page, or only on an external site. If your app is made to work in a page tab, it's quite important that your page gets a lot of likes because the users will see it .. ?

Comment: @dwarfy Like I said I am running this  app on a domain and my fan page really don't have anything as of now, just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, but I'll try to give you a summary:

1. If your items (pages) that will have a Like button are accessible through an external website (e.g. a blog post) then go for **option 2**
2. If these items will only be accessible through the Facebook app (or meant to be accessible mainly through the app), then go for **option 1**. This way, if you had to move the site to another domian..etc you don't have to worry about losing the "likes" (because the links that being liked will be something like: `http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/item/5` and won't get affected)
3. In my opinion, you should always have a Like button for your "*brand*" fan page (**option 3**) somewhere in your app!

Comment: Good point to keep in mind if domain can be changed. When can one see a message like "user started using blah-blah app", is it because of liking the app or the first time one starts using it?

Comment: Start using an app doesn't necessary means the user "Authorized" the app, so I guess this would appear when that happens (user allow the app)

Comment: @ifavour Whats that suppose to mean? How can I start using an app unless I authorize it for permissions, its asking for?

Comment: @Ashfame you may have an app that doesn't require user info (anonymous access). Anyway I guess this is not the case with you.

Comment: @ifavour oh you mean accessing publicly available data from graph API, yeah thats not the case with me. Can you tell me when that message exactly comes?